# Not able to load files larger than 100 MB into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, data-ingestion

I'm facing a really strange issue with my cluster.

Whenever I'm trying to load any file into HDFS that is larger than 100 MB(104857600 bytes) it fails with the following error:

> All datanodes are bad... Aborting.

This is really strange as 100 MB has become the threshold for filesize.

Even if i try to increase the file size by 1 single byte (104857601 bytes), and try to load it in HDFS,  it fails with a long stacktrace. Principally saying "All datanodes are bad... Aborting"

Has anybody faced similar situation earlier?

Is it possible that there's some configuration change by mistake which has led to this behaviour? If yes, any configuration that limits the size of data that can be ingested that i can change?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you able to load in multiple files of 51 mb? How do you load it in, and does it fail immediately or near the end? Any chance that you set a very low memory limit for mappers?

Comment: Have you checked your split size and max open file handles limit?

Comment: @Dennis - I'm able to load anything below than 100 MB. Loading using hadoop fs -put. It fails immediately. I'm not sure how to check for the memory limit though. Please clarify the same.

Comment: @mbaxi - how do i check the split size? Max open file handles limit is set to unlimited.

Comment: @MeghVidani- try changing split size using mapred.max.split.size parmeter

Comment: @red - I guess you're talking about mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize? It is set to default Long.MAX_VALUE. What should I change it to?

Comment: @MeghVidani-yes what is your current value?

Comment: I don't find that property in the mapred-site.xml file. Guess it's set to Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @MeghVidani try to set it to 1/4 your block size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Has anybody faced similar situation earlier?"

Yes I had. You should decrease the limit for the user who runs hadoop. 
I installed hadoop on a linux box downloading it from apache website, and my system was not tuned for it, I got your message. These are the settings from cloudera quick start, compare your limit with these.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ulimit -a 
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30494
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured that out before your answer came but this will surely help others.

Comment: @MeghVidani what changes did you make?

Comment: @red I edited the /etc/security/limits.conf file and set the file size limit to unlimited. Earlier it was set to 102400 KB(100 MB)

Comment: @MeghVidani It is great if you find the answer to your own question, but please state it here in that case. Both for future reference, and for people who otherwise may find the same solution as you after a thorough search.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin - I have already marked this answer as accepted, what else could I possibly add?

Comment: @MeghVidani Because you mentioned ' I actually figured that out before your answer came' I decided to make a suggestion for how to handle this on future occasions. As you have already received and accepted an answer here, there is indeed no need for further action regarding this question.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin- okay. I was actually going to answer this one myself. But before I got chance to do so, ozw1z5rd had already posted a solution. I'll keep you suggestion in mind though.

Answer (score 0):

If the you are able to get more details of the data node from the stack trace, you should be able to stop the datanode which would be one the daemons.
By killing or stopping the datanode you would get the data node which is likely to be corrupted, re-instantiated. Basically you are restarting jvm of that particular datanode.
Command:
 To stop: `bin/hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode`
 To start: `bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode`

Comment: Hi, I'm facing that error with all the datanodes. I have 5 datanodes in the cluster and it tries all of them in turn. All failing with the same error.